# How to save dataGridView changed data?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, code-first, mvp

I'm try to create database application and implement **MVP pattern**.
I'm using EF+CodeFirst.
There is `View`, `Presenter` and `Model`.

View have `dataGridView` and `SetData()` method.

```
public void SetData(IEnumerable<Goods> items)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = items.ToList();
}
```

Presenter retrieve data from Model and call SetData() of View.

```
internal void Select()
{
    var data = _modelGoods.Select();
    _view.SetData(data);
}
```

But, how to save a changed cell data?

Comment: If you are working with disconnected entities, you should track entity changes. Some of your entities are added, some of them are changed and some of them are deleted. And you want to insert those added entities and update those changed entities and delete those deleted entities from context.

Comment: @RezaAghaei It is called Disconnected Scenario?

Comment: If you get data using a service, and you have no access to the context that you get data from it, then this is disconnected. In a connected scenario, for example, you create an instance of context in your form, and get data and manipulate data and then save changes to context.

Comment: I can share a simple example of how it works in connected scenario if you think it may be helpful.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Yes please. If you will not be difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, to update a record using EF, you read the entity object first, update the property values with the new values, the save it back.

Something like this.

```
var idOfRecord=12;
using(var yourDbContext=new YourDbContext())
{
  var good=yourDbContext.Goods.FirstOrDefault(s=>s.Id==idOfRecord);
  if(good!=null)
  {
    good.Name = "New name read from UI"; //Updating the Name property value
    yourDbContext.Entry(good).State = EntityState.Modified;
    yourDbContext.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

Assuming `YourDbContext` is the name of your `DbContext` class. Update the property/class names as needed to match your use case.

Comment: How I know which exactly cell have been to changed - name or something else?

Comment: Sorry ! I am not sure. Not a winform expert. But i guess you should be able to pass some unique id back to your code to track that. My answer was explaining how generally updating data works in EF.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with connected entities, the job is simple, you can load data in context and then bind data to the grid and manipulate data and at last call `SaveChanges` of the context that you loaded data, to apply changes to database.

If you are working with disconnected entities, you should track entity changes. Some of your entities are added, some of them are changed and some of them are deleted. And you want to insert those added entities and update those changed entities and delete those deleted entities from context. To do so you can inherit from a `BindigList<T>` or an `ObservableCOllection<T>` or use a `BindingSource` and listen to list changes events and track changes and store changes in 3 separated lists (added, changed, deleted) and then pass these lists to the server to apply changes.

**Sample for Connected Entities:**

```
SampleDbContext db;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    db = new SampleDbContext();
    db.Products.Load();
    this.productDataGridView.DataSource = db.Products.Local.ToBindingList();
}
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.productDataGridView.EndEdit();
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Sample for Disconnected Entities:**

I suppose you have tracked changes using `BindingSource` or `BindingList<T>` or `ObservableCollection<T>` or even using `DataGridView` events or something else. Now you should have added, edited and deleted entities and you can pass them to your server code to apply changes this way:

```
public void SaveChanges(List<Product> added, List<Product> edited, List<Product> deleted)
{
    using (var db = new SampleDbContext())
    {
        foreach (var entity in deleted)
        {
            if (edited.Contains(entity))
                edited.Remove(entity);

            if (added.Contains(entity))
                added.Remove(entity);
            else
                db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        }

        foreach (var entity in added)
        {
            if (edited.Contains(entity))
                edited.Remove(entity);
            db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
        }

        foreach (var entity in edited)
            db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Disconnected approach looks very terrible. But in [this](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/attach-disconnected-entity-graph.aspx) tutorial nothing is said about tracking changes. Where I cant learn more about it?

Comment: I didn't say it is a good approach, but It is a very simple approach for applications that may work connected, and I'm not sure if you are working disconnected or connected. Also I think the sample is a good example of how to work connected and would be helpful for future readers :)

Comment: Also added an example of how to save disconnected data.

Comment: OK. That is very interesting and i will sort out. But how i can pass changed data from dataGridView?

Comment: Changed data are not stored in `DataGridView`, in fact `DataGridView` is only a presentation layer to apply changes on a data source. You should track changes of the data source and store changes in `added`, `edited` and `deleted` lists and then when saving, pass them to such method. You should start with tacking changes. It's not trivial a task.

Comment: I believe the post answers the question **How to save DataGridView changed data?**. While the post guides you to how to save connected data and shows how to save disconnected data, but it doesn't contain any implementation of change detection mechanism and only shares some idea about how to detect changes. I think **How to track entities changes in a WinForms application** can be your new question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a expert of MVP pattern, if based on the examples view know about model,
then you can use `DataGridView.CellEndEdit` eventhandler

```
private void dgvtest1_CellEndEdit(Object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.RowIndex < 0)
        return;
    if(e.ColumnIndex < 0)
        return;
    DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
    DataGridViewRow row = dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex);
    Good model = row.DataBoundItem as Good
    if(model == null)
        return;
    //Then decide which property was changed and update it
    String boundPropertyName= dgv.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).DataPropertyName;
    if(boundPropertyName.Equals(nameOf(model.SomeProperty)) == true)
    {
        //Update value
        return;
    }
    //.. other columns
}
```